# Using StandardPaths with UseAppInfo function in wxPython

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I am using wxPython 4.2.0 to get standard directories using:

```
standardPaths = wx.StandardPaths.Get()
dataDir = standardPaths.GetUserLocalDataDir()
```

and this returns  `C:\\Users\\john_smith\\AppData\\Local\\app_name_debug_helper` but I want it to return  `C:\\Users\\john_smith\\AppData\\Local\\something_else`. I found that I can set the app name using

```
wx.GetApp().SetAppName("something_else)
```

but the app name is actually used elsewhere so I hoped to turn off app name usage by passing `AppInfo_None` to `UseAppInfo(info)` as documented [here](https://docs.wxpython.org/wx.StandardPaths.html#wx.StandardPaths.UseAppInfo) and then appending my own directory as needed.

However, `AppInfo_None` does not appear to be defined. In wxWidgets, `AppInfo_None` is `wxStandardPaths::AppInfo_None` but in wxPython I am not sure if these parameters are actually available. Are they and how?

Answer (score 1):

Just setting it to zero seems to do the trick `UseAppInfo(0)`.

The valid values appear to be 0, 1, 2 and 3

```
>>> import wx
>>> a = wx.App()
>>> s = wx.StandardPaths.Get()
>>> s.UserDataDir
'/home/rolf/.python3'
>>> 
>>> 
>>> wx.GetApp().SetAppName("my_app")
>>> wx.GetApp().SetVendorName("Rolf")
>>> s.UserDataDir
'/home/rolf/.my_app'
>>> 
>>> s.UseAppInfo(0)
>>> s.UserDataDir
'/home/rolf/.'
>>> 
>>> s.UseAppInfo(1)
>>> s.UserDataDir
'/home/rolf/.my_app'
>>> 
>>> s.UseAppInfo(2)
>>> s.UserDataDir
'/home/rolf/.Rolf'
>>> 
>>> s.UseAppInfo(3)
>>> s.UserDataDir
'/home/rolf/.Rolf/my_app'
>>>
```

Comment: I don't know if they're expose in Python, but C++ values are `AppInfo_None` (0), `AppInfo_AppName` (1) and `AppInfo_VendorName` (2) respectively, and the last two can be combined.